# What does '-- --daemon' mean in start-stop-daemon?

Tags: linux, command, start-stop-daemon

On [this man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html) for `start-stop-daemon`, there is an example:

```
  start-stop-daemon --start --oknodo --user food --name food --pidfile \
     /var/run/food.pid --startas /usr/sbin/food --chuid food -- --daemon
```

Can anyone explain what the last couple of items mean (i.e. the "`-- --daemon`" part)? It doesn't seem to be covered in the rest of the document and I'm confused by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same man page link you provide in your question:

> **COMMANDS**
>   -S, --start [--] arguments
>   ...
>   Any  arguments  given  after  **--**  on the command line are passed unmodified to the program being started.

So `--daemon` will be passed onto `/usr/sbin/food` in your example.